# loading resource works locally but not on server

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat, windows-server-2008

First of all i've tried my code by extracting the war file (using maven) on both eclipse and on a tomcat 8.0.33 stand alone on my mac.

I have also tried my code on a windows server 2008 with the same java version 1.8, and it works when i put some variable (which are username and password) hardcoded, but when i make the code to read them from a reousrce file, it is just working on my mac (both eclipse and tomcat stand alone), but not on the server

this is the code to read the resource

```
private static String getUsername() {
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        InputStream input = null;

        try {

            input = new FileInputStream(MyConfiguration.class.getClassLoader()
                    .getResource("configuration.properties").getFile());

            // load a properties file
            prop.load(input);

            // get the property value and print it out
            return prop.getProperty("username");

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (input != null) {
                try {
                    input.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

where the location of the `configuration.properties` is in the `src/main/resources` and on the server, i can see that file is in the correct directory.

i am using maven, i don't know what other information you need to help me, but if you say, i will give you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try
`input = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("configuration.properties");`

Comment: Exactly, no reason to use a File here. When `configuration.properties` is bundled inside a war you cannot access it as File. The reason that it works in your IDE is because you can still access it as a file. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SUREFIRE-855 is related to this, it now lets you test with the artifact instead of the classfolder, just like "in production".

Answer (score 0):

Open your war and the jar file that contains your application. Ensure that the resource you are trying to open is in the jar (in the war) that is getting deployed. Most of the times this has happened to me, it's because I failed to tell my build process that this file needed to be copied over to the deployment. Class files go automatically, but not always resource files.

Comment: i said in the question, it is there, i can see it